# Package is not found after running roscore

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use **catkin_make** to build a package. It works . I then proceed to source the generated setup file in order to add my workspace to my ROS environment. (**. ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash**). Using rospack I can display the dependecies of the package. But then when I run **roscore** and look again for package (or use **rosrun**) I get and error that **there is no such package.** . Did I miss a step?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280157/package-is-not-found-after-running-roscore/) by [newrosy](https://answers.ros.org/users/33336/newrosy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm assuming that when you started **roscore** you then created a new terminal window to execute the **rosrun** command. You need to source the setup.bash file for you package in every terminal you open (it only effects the terminal is sourced in)

If you missed this step then it would explain the problem you're having. Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [newrosy](https://answers.ros.org/users/33336/newrosy/) on 2018-01-18**:
That's it! Thank you! But I am wondering why it does not work since I checked  my .bashrc file and I found the line : source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash so I assumed it should apply to all terminals and it is not required to write this command every time I am using a new terminal

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-18**:
Note that you can add `source ~\catkin_ws\devel\setup.bash` to your `.bashrc` file to avoid this problem. But, if you have multiple workspaces then that would introduce another issue.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-18**:
What jayess just said. You need to source the setup.bash files for ros as a whole and your package for it to work. If you've got one workspace then put it in .bash and save yourself a lot of typing!

**Comment by [newrosy](https://answers.ros.org/users/33336/newrosy/) on 2018-01-18**:
Great thanks! everything is fine now!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-18**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd: what do you mean exactly with:

> You need to source the setup.bash files for ros as a whole and your package for it to work.

**Comment by [Catman](https://answers.ros.org/users/51820/catman/) on 2020-02-16**:
Thank you so much! I was dumb enough to uninstall ros for such small problem
I copied souce ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash to .bashrc file and now everything is working just fine